# Removed post due to "company owner"

Tags: discussion, rules

Recently I answered a question that was stated on stackoverflow regarding rest documentation. In my answer, I stated the following (quote):

"you might also consider ..... It grew from a tool we use within our own company and it's free to use for open source projects. It does exactly what you describe."

The tool actually does indeed solve the problem stated by the user. I never concealed that I was one of the authors. My answer was commented on by another user with the remark 'Whois states that you are the owner of the company, spam' and the answer was removed by a moderator in minutes.

Is it forbidden to make note of a solution you developed, simply because you developed it and if the tool is freely available for open source?

Once again, I didn't mean to blatantly advertise and apologize for the infriction. Please let me know what is acceptable for future answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So long as there is full disclosure, as far as the "rules" go, it is fine, so long as the answer is relevant to the question.

What seems to have happened is that the commenter also flagged the answer as spam and a moderator deleted it as result.

Reading through, it does look OK to me - there is full disclosure. I have undeleted it now.

Do note, that some people don't like any kind of self-promotion on Stack Overflow and will flag such answers as spam. That's the nature of a community driven site.

Comment: Oh; I deleted that one! I agree with it being undeleted. Didn't look quite the same in the flag queue...

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Yeah, I guess being on that queue may introduce a bit of bias.

Comment: And I try to be so careful with Spam flags, in particular. Just cleared two, in fact. Sometimes people flag the oddest things as 'Spam' (though I can see how someone might have classified that as 'spam', I guess)\

Comment: @AndrewBarber - The fact is, some people don't like any sort of self promotion...